# Unity conversions in transmission delay

Tags: networking

I'm currently learning about transmission delay and propagation. I'm really having a tough time with the conversions. I understand how it all works but I cant get through the converting. For example:

`8000bits/5mbps(mega bits per second)` I have no idea how to do this conversion , I've tried looking online but no one explains how the conversion happens. I'm supposed to get 1.6 ms, but I cannot see how the heck that happens. I tried doing it this way, `8000b / 5x10^6 b/s` but that gives me `1600 s`.

Comment: 1/ The example you give is not delay, it's throughput (which is _very_ different) 2/ It's unclear what you're asking: conversion from what (unit) to what (unit)? Ex:  you want to convert `8000bits/5mbps(mega bits per second)` to which unit? Side note: "I understand how it all works", yet "but I cant get through the converting" imply no, sorry but you do not understand how it all works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(because that would not fit in a comment):

8000 bits = 8000 / 1000 = 8 kbit, or 8000 / 1000 / 1000 = 0.008 mbit.

(or 8000 / 1024 = 7.8 Kibit, or 8000 / 1024 / 1024 = 0.0076 Mibit,

see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_rate_units)

Say you have a throughput of 5mbps (mega bits per second), to transmit your 8000 bits that's:

**( 0.008 mbit) / (5 mbit/s) = 0.0016 s = 1.6 ms**

That is, unit wise:

bit / (bit/s)

bit divided by bit => the bit unit disappear,

then divide and divide by seconds = not "something per second", but second,

result unit is second.